# Related to head and tail command in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I know what output `head -n` and `tail -n` will provide.

Is there any command like `head +n` (`head +2 filename`) or `tail +n` (`tail +2 filename`)?

If yes, can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What are those commands supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`tail` supports both positive and negative offsets, but `head` does not.

Start output at the 10th line from the end of the file:

```
tail -10 filename
```

Start out at the 10th line from the begining of the file:

```
tail +10 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The Single Unix Specification Version 2 (1997) [states the following for `tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tail.html):

> In the non-obsolescent form, if neither **-c** nor **-n** is specified, **-n 10** is assumed.
>
> In the obsolescent version, an argument beginning with a "-" or "+" can be used as a single option. The argument ±*number* with the letter c specified as a suffix is equivalent to **-c** ±*number*; ±*number* with the b suffix is equivalent to **-c** ±*number**512; ±*number* with the letter l specified as a suffix, or with none of b, c nor l as a suffix, is equivalent to **-n** ±*number*. If *number* is not specified in these forms, 10 will be used. The letter f specified as a suffix is equivalent to specifying the **-f** option. If the **[*number*]c[f]** form is used and neither *number* nor the f suffix is specified, it will be interpreted as the **-c 10** option.

In other words the following commands in each group are equivalent:

```
tail -2 file
tail -n 2 file

tail +2 file
tail -n +2

tail -2c file
tail -c 2 file

tail +3lf file
tail -f -n +3 file
```

Note that unless a "+" is used, the number given means "output the last N lines". If "+" is used, it means "output the lines starting from line N". For example, in a file with 40 lines, `tail +2` (or equivalently `tail -n +2`) would output lines 2..40, whereas using -2 or simply 2 would output lines 39..40.

The next version of the Single Unix Specification of 2001 [removed the obsolescent form completely](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tail.html), so there are no "options" starting with a "+" character.

Answer (score 0):

I think piping is what you're looking for: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)

To use the first example you gave:

`head +2 filename | head +n`

I believe is what you want, though note that I haven't tested it